# Using the return type IQueryable<TABLE_1>

Tags: silverlight-4.0, ienumerable, observablecollection, iqueryable

I am new to silverlight, many posts indicate using observablecollection is the best.

Domainservice1 returns IQUERYABLE type.

> How to work with this return type in
>   silverlight side?
>
> How to convert/cast the data returned
>   to observable collection?

***The DomainServices1.cs***

```
public IQueryable<TABLE_1> GetTABLE_1()
        {

            return this.ObjectContext.TABLE_1;
        }
```

*The HOME.XAML.CS***

```
public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Title = ApplicationStrings.HomePageTitle;


            Web.DomainService1 dservice = new Web.DomainService1();

            EntityQuery<Web.TABLE_1> query=new EntityQuery<Web.TABLE_1>();

            query = dservice.GetTABLE_1Query();

            //Convert result to ObservableCollection

            //bind the grid ITEM SOURCE

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The IQueryable does not return results until you enumerate the collection. so for instance if you wanted to limit the results of that dservice.getTable_1Query with a .where() you could...

to get the object into an observable collection you .tolist the query like this

```
observablecollection<Table1> t=new observablecollection<Table1>(query.ToList());
```

I actually think there is a little more that you have to do(a loadoperation is how I do mine)
I am in the learning stages of the linq dynamic, but from other applications that i have had to convert returned results to an observable collection; that is how i did it. I actually wrote an exension so that I could .ToObservableCollection